# Fibonacci Sequence Generator in C++

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I am trying to make a Fibonacci Sequence Generator in C++ and was having some trouble. I am new to C++ and was trying to make this work as I have done it in other languages that I know.  So I wrote a program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int NextNumber(int x, int y, int z)
{
    z=x+y;
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    int q;
    int w;
    int x=0;
    int y=1;
    int z=1;
    int t=1;
    cout << x;
    cout << ", "<< y ;
    cout << ", "<< z ;
    while (t<10)
        x=NextNumber(y,z,x);
        cout << ", "<< x ;
        q=y; //Q is farthest back
        w=z; //W is in the middle
        z=x; //Z moves from middle to front
        y=w; //Y moves from back to middle
        x=q; //X moves from front to back
        t=t+1; //Add a rotation to the while loop
}
```

I am using Xcode to compile and it appears that no output is displayed when I run the program.  If anyone has any thoughts on why this may be happening or if my program has any logical flaws please help.  Thank you.

Comment: It would help to put `<<std::endl' after you didsplay `x` so you actually display things on a new line. Check your projects parameters to make sure you're making a console program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is not Python, and white spaces are ignored by the compiler. You must use braces for the `while` loop,

```
while (t<10)
{
  // details
} // end loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not used to the syntax very much and that fixed it.